# Import multiple playbooks with order

Tags: ansible

I have this in playboook.yml

```
- import_playbook: A.yml
- import_playbook: B.yml
- import_playbook: C.yml
```

Hosts:

```
[hostA]
178.112.32.12
178.112.32.13
```

```
[hostC]
178.112.32.14
```

A.yml

```
- hosts: 
    - hostA
  serial: 1

  name: 'A'
  roles:
    - roles/roleA
```

B.yml

```
- hosts: 
    - hostA
  serial: 1

  name: 'B'
  roles:
    - roles/roleB1
    - roles/roleB2
```

C.yml

```
- hosts: 
    - hostC
  serial: 1

  name: 'C'
  roles:
    - roles/roleC1
    - roles/roleC2
    - roles/roleC3
```

I want to run A, B and C playbooks in order by host ip (with serial), that is:

```
178.112.32.12 - roleA
178.112.32.12 - roleB1
178.112.32.12 - roleB2
178.112.32.14 - roleC1
178.112.32.14 - roleC2
178.112.32.14 - roleC3

and only after

178.112.32.13 - roleA
178.112.32.13 - roleB1
178.112.32.13 - roleB2
178.112.32.14 - roleC1
178.112.32.14 - roleC2
178.112.32.14 - roleC3
```

Basically, I want to run playbooks by import order and one host after another (first *.12, second: *.13)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the playbook dynamically from the data you got. For example (I'm not sure if this is the correct order. If not, fit it to your needs.)

```sh
shell> cat pb-list.txt 
178.112.32.12 - roleA
178.112.32.12 - roleB1
178.112.32.12 - roleB2
178.112.32.14 - roleC1
178.112.32.14 - roleC2
178.112.32.14 - roleC3
178.112.32.13 - roleA
178.112.32.13 - roleB1
178.112.32.13 - roleB2
178.112.32.14 - roleC1
178.112.32.14 - roleC2
178.112.32.14 - roleC3
```

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        pbl: "{{ lookup('file', 'pb-list.txt').splitlines()|list }}"
    - copy:
        dest: playbook.yml
        content: |
          {% for line in pbl %}
          - hosts: {{ line.split('-').0|trim }}
            roles: roles/{{ line.split('-').1|trim }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives the playbook that will do what you want

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: 178.112.32.12
  roles: roles/roleA
- hosts: 178.112.32.12
  roles: roles/roleB1
- hosts: 178.112.32.12
  roles: roles/roleB2
- hosts: 178.112.32.14
  roles: roles/roleC1
- hosts: 178.112.32.14
  roles: roles/roleC2
- hosts: 178.112.32.14
  roles: roles/roleC3
- hosts: 178.112.32.13
  roles: roles/roleA
- hosts: 178.112.32.13
  roles: roles/roleB1
- hosts: 178.112.32.13
  roles: roles/roleB2
- hosts: 178.112.32.14
  roles: roles/roleC1
- hosts: 178.112.32.14
  roles: roles/roleC2
- hosts: 178.112.32.14
  roles: roles/roleC3
```

This will reduce your problem to the generation of the pb-list.txt files.